# the needle in gauge does not show the correct value

Tags: powerbi, report, dashboard, gauge

I'm using  Tachometer in Power bi. it worked great for a while but now it the needle does not show the correct value. it always shows the max value. I set it to show a ratio if not os less then Q2 with green, between Q2 and Q3 with yellow and higher with red, as shown in the picture. Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?
<image[image]

Comment: You can check your background data by exporting. Also you need to check why value is reaching maximum value or greater that maximum value. Can you share your measure code for the value field?

Comment: the value does not reach the max value. As it is shown the value is 55.54 but the needle shows 1. the value is the ratio of damaged items over total sold items

Comment: Your Max value set to 1 and Value is 55.54. this is normal it will point at the maximum point. I think you need to convert all other value considering 0 to 100 as well.

Comment: how a big mistake. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per nature of Gauge or Tachometer, your pointer will always show at the Maximum point if your Value is equal to your maximum value or greater than that.

In your given image, I can see Your Max value set to 1 and Value is 55.54. this is normal it will point at the maximum point. I think you need to convert all other value considering 0 to 100 as well.